# Should I use Expo for making a small cross paltform app?

Tags: ios, windows, react-native, mobile, expo

After a month o f making an app in react-native vanilla, realisede today, that i wont be able to make the Ios side without an MacOS machine.

As i only have Windows and this is just a first try for me of making an an app, i wonder is it worth trying to remake the app using expo-cli. I am just unsure, coz everwhere is said that it is now adviced.

My point is that my app i a simple "chat-room" based application, that only includes transfering data between the client and the abckend ( firebase). Is it okay to ue expo in this case?

Comment: As before: you're asking for a technology recommendation, which is still off-topic here on Stack Overflow. But if you search for [how to make an iOS app on Windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+an+ios+app+on+windows) you're bound to find relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, expo is a great option to make cross platform apps with! I use expo all the time for quick apps. The reason why expo is more preferred for starters is that you don't require an emulator to render your app. You can easily view it on your own phone screen or web version (or even use an emulator if you want).

Expo is a good option for your chat room app as well.

> [Here's](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/getting-started#:~:text=Running%20your%20React%20Native%20application,instructions%20to%20get%20a%20link.) how you can get started with expo